Real-time free musical pitch recognition software for Windows
Can you suggest me some free Windows software, that
can recognise the musical pitch sung by the user,
or emitted by a musical instructment?
I have checked a free open-source software
Sonic Visualiser, it did can recognise the pitch,
but it seems to be only able to do it offlinely,
that is, not real-time.
I have also checked GNU Solfege, but it seems
to be unable to hear. That is, it hasn't functions
to process the sound it hears.
I have also checked a software called oTuner.
Although the comments at the download page suggest that
it works fine, on my device it doesn't work properly,
that when I play a C, it says F. I think maybe it
is not fully tested on the Windows 10 system, considering
its old age. However, please tell me if you find it works
well on ur Windows 10/11 device - that might suggest
that oTuner is the one I'm looking for, just that there
is some problems on my
own device.
I also saw a similar post, but what that post
is about is not exactly the same software
I am looking for: Musical notes listener

PitchPerfect Guitar Tuner. It can recognise human voice as well.

Free.
Great interface.
Really real time and fast.

